# How we can convert SQL to LINQ or Entity

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, .net-core, entity

Ok!!! Now i have something like this:

```
 var groupCloseCell = from close_cell in _context.ClosedCells
                            where close_cell.StatusActive == false
                            group close_cell by close_cell.AccessCellId into g
                            select new
                            {
                                AccessCellId = g.Key, 
                                Close = g.Count()
                            } ;

            var grouping = (from schedule in _context.Schedules
                       join sa in _context.ScheduleAttributes on schedule.Id equals sa.ScheduleId into sa
                       from scheduleAtr in sa.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       join ac in _context.AccessCells on scheduleAtr.Id equals ac.ScheduleAttrId into ac
                       from accessCell in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       join cc in groupCloseCell on accessCell.Id equals cc.AccessCellId into cc
                       from closeCell in cc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new 
                       {
                           schedule = schedule,
                           scheduleAtr = scheduleAtr,
                           accessCell = accessCell,
                           **closedCell = closeCell**
                       }).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But there are problems I have highlighted in bold in which place. **Nullable object must have a value**

INNER JOIN WORKING, LEFT JOIN Exception, why?

Comment: What is "Linq OR Entity"?

Comment: @GuruStron lar qry = from x in source.Foo where x.SomeProp == "abc"  select x.Bar;   **OR** var qry = source.Foo.Where(x => x.SomeProp == "abc").Select(x => x.Bar);

Comment: Both of them are LINQ. One is query syntax another - method syntax (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create a Linq query with a left join then you can look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins).

Using the `with` statement as a starting point, you can link multiple Linq queries:

```
var testQuery = from cc in _context.ClosedCells 
                // additional clauses here
                select new 
                {
                    // properties here
                    AccessCellId = cc.id_access_cell
                };
     
var query = from schedule in _context.Schedules
            join tin testQuery on schedule.Id equals t.AccessCellId into closed_cells
            from cc in closed_cells.DefaultIfEmpty()
            // more clauses
            select new S
            {
                // properties here
            };
```

Comment: OK! But how i can get sum(1) in closedCells

Comment: One of the examples in the Microsoft documentation shows [`group student by student.LastName into newGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results#group-by-single-property-example) then you simply use `newGroup.Count()` in the appropriate place.